# Is there a way to use a variable without the need of defining it (in R)?

Tags: r, variables, rbind, cbind

I use following code:

```
tempdata <- rbind(tempdata,newdata)  # bind rowwise
```

as far as I know, tempdata (like all objects, variables, ...) needs to be defined. Because there are only numerical values, I define it as `tempdata<-0`. It's not a really big problem, but when using rbind afterwards, the first row with `0` is kept at the first place and I have to use some kind of

```
tempdata<-tempdata[-1,] # deletes first row
```

I can't define it as `tempdata<-''`, because this would be a character, right?

Well as I said, not really a problem for me, but would there be a better way, especially if I or someone would use `rbind()` many times in the code and therefore maybe the first row has to be "cleared" not only once...

The same could be a problem when using `cbind()`.

Maybe someone knows a better solution?

Comment: Define `tempdata <- numeric(0)`, then `rbind`/`cbind` results will not contain unwanted data.

Comment: @tonytonov: thanks, I will try this, should work!

Comment: `tempdata <- NULL` would also work

Comment: @jbaums: thumbs up! thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using `rbind`/`cbind` to build some results from an iterative procedure, you may declare the  "empty" object to store the data in. For numeric data, use `numeric(0)`, which is a zero-length numeric  vector. It is compatible with any binding:

```
rbind(numeric(0), 1:3)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
cbind(numeric(0), 1:3)
     [,1]
[1,]    1
[2,]    2
[3,]    3
```

The same holds for `NULL` (as pointed by @jbaums). It may even be more convenient since you don't have to specify the data type manually (the same will also work with `numeric(0)` due to implicit type conversion):

```
rbind(NULL, letters[1:3])
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] "a"  "b"  "c"
```